# Remote control OPC ip address

Tags: automation, plc, opc-ua, opc

I am new with OPC UA world and I need to getting start with this. I have a company in witch there is a new machinery that is an opc server. This machinery is actually linked in internet with dhcp. In particular, I need to understand:

For remote control on the same network I only need to take the ip address (eventually static) and I can monitor and write values of the server, is this right?

Answer (score 0):

OPC UA server provide different endpoints, typically in the form of `opc.tcp://myOPCUAServer:12345/path` those endpoints can be discovered using the local IP address or DNS name. Your OPC UA stack typically provide functionality to list all the endpoints, like [DiscoveryClient.GetEndpoints()](https://cs.github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/1d123da6a9ee11aeb89b7c708360df7d26ced852/Stack/Opc.Ua.Core/Stack/Client/DiscoveryClient.cs#L151) and than select one for you [CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint()](https://cs.github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/1d123da6a9ee11aeb89b7c708360df7d26ced852/Libraries/Opc.Ua.Client/CoreClientUtils.cs#L240).

Often endpoint support different connection settings like Security Policy (e.g. Basic256Sha256), Message Security Mode (e.g. SignAndEncrypt) and User Authentication (Anonymous, Username/Password, Certificate). Your client connection would need to support the same, in order to connect.